# Get Data from json in yii through jquery

Tags: jquery, json, yii

My json data looks somthing like this 
`[{"id":"299","calendar_id":"49","event_date":"2012-11-27","event_start":"2012-11-27 00:39:00","event_end":"2012-11-27 00:39:00","title":"description goes here","description":"","planned":"0","type_class":"General","type_data":"{\"frequency_type\":\"1\",\"frequency_x\":null,\"type\":\"14\",\"status\":\"23\"}"`
Ajax request

```
$.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo $this->createUrl('path/to/file')?>",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            var out = "<span>";
            $(data).each(function(){
                out += this.title;
            });
            out += "</span>";
            unplannedList.html(out);
            }
var unplannedList = $('.col ul li');
```

It's a list where I need to append my data which is displayed at the top. 'this' or 'data' doesn't work. What is the correct way of getting the data from the alert I have pasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you are trying to make each one a separate span.. Or put all the titles into one span.  But here's how it should be using [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function

```
var out = '';
$.each(data,function(k,v){ // <-- using the callback arguments
    out += '<span>'+v.title+'</span>';
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/2CMjL/)

Comment: Your fiddle works perfect but not my code. If I try to alert data inside $.each(data,function(k,v){ alert('in');} it does not alert anything. possibly I am somewhere wrong. but just before if I alert the data it does alert. Strange.

Comment: do a console.log(data) outside the each to see if you are receiving a javascript object.. then do a console.log(v) to make sure you are getting the each object inside the each function

Comment: console.log(data) should ideally display the data in firebug console window right? There's nothing displayed there, blank after '>>>'

Comment: Yeah it should.. it means you aren't getting any JSON response.. How are you getting the JSON?  From a file? or is it a server response?

Comment: Thank you! It was server response error. I would have never noticed it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access that object in that way you are trying. You need a referenct to the currient object to access to your *this*. Try something like this:

```
var self=this;
```

and work in your callback with self.

Comment: CAn you elaborate your answer?

Comment: I think your *this* is in another scope so that *this* is not that *this* which your are expecting. If you make a *local copy* you can be sure that the meaning won't change.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$(data).each(...)`, try this:

```
$.each(data, function() {
   out += this.title;
});
```

Comment: No luck there. Still the same. It doesn't put anything in the list

Comment: Then, similar to the comments on the answer below, check your json source URL.  Is returning data?  Or perhaps you're getting a 404 or 500 error?